# Running time of sorting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I have written a function to sort time stamps `(hh:mm:ss)` in order from oldest to newest. I am interested in knowing the approximate worst case running time of my code but i don't know how to determine that.

My rough guess is `O(n-1)^2` because of nested `for loop`. Am i correct ?

If not, then can someone determine what would be the approximate running time of my code in `Big O` notation ?

```
public void sortTimeStamp(SortTime timestamps[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<timestamps.length-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<timestamps.length-1;j++)
        {
            if(timestamps[j].hour > timestamps[j+1].hour)
            {
                swap_timestamps(timestamps, j);
            }
            else
            if(timestamps[j].hour == timestamps[j+1].hour)
            {
                if(timestamps[j].minutes > timestamps[j+1].minutes)
                {
                     swap_timestamps(timestamps, j);
                }
                else
                if(timestamps[j].minutes == timestamps[j+1].minutes && timestamps[j].seconds > timestamps[j+1].seconds)
                {
                    swap_timestamps(timestamps, j);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Swap function

```
public void swap_timestamps(SortTime timestamps[], int index)
    {
        SortTime temp = timestamps[index];
        timestamps[index] = timestamps[index+1];
        timestamps[index+1] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: why `for(int i=0;i<4;i++)` ? this means that your array will always have 4 elementd?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be `O(n^2)`, assuming that your loops intend to iterate over the full length of the `SortTime` object/collection.

Comment: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: @jsalatas my array is of size 5.

Comment: so why bother about the complexity as we are talking for only 5 elements? :)

Comment: Hint: I would bother less about runtime characteristics but other qualities of your code: like readability, maintainability, ... because well, you are not exactly doing good in those dimensions (for example by using a **fixed** number 4 there; instead of just going for s.length instead ... and s being a super-poor name too).

Comment: @GhostCat i agree. I was interested in time complexity because i am preparing for an exam which will include questions related to time complexity of different algorithms.

Comment: @GhostCat edited the code to make it more readable and understandable as you suggested.

Comment: Better ;-) another code review hint: you have duplicated that "swapping" code three times. In real life, you would want to put that into a little helper method! Code duplication is one of the roots of evil!

Comment: @GhostCat done that too. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this sorting algorithm is O(n^2). 
Your answer is `O((n-1)^2)`, and it is equal to `O(n^2-2n+1)`. 
But the big-O notation `O(f(n))` means "the time is approximately proportional for `f(n)`" (not exactly correct, but it's easy to understand)
So you don't have to think `-2n` or `1` term.
You can only think about `n^2` term, and you don't need any coefficients.

But you can do mergesort and the time complexity is O(n log n)
Counting sort is OK because hh:mm:ss can express only 86400 ways. It accomplish O(n+k) where k=86400.

Comment: thanks for your response. +1 for simple explanation.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that the O(n) notation applies when n is large, so limit theory can be applied. When n->Inf, then O(n^2-2n+1) ->O(n^2).